# How to construct NHibernate criteria to find parents who has all specified children

Tags: nhibernate, subquery

A Project can have many Parts.  A property on Part is Ipn, which is a string of digits.

- Project "A" has Parts "1", "2", "3"
- Project "B" has Parts "2", "3", "4"
- Project "C" has Parts "2"
- Project "D" has Parts "3"

I want to find all Projects that have all of the specified parts associated with it.  My current query is

```
            var ipns = new List<String> { "2", "3" }

            var criteriaForIpns = DetachedCriteria
                .For<Part>()
                .SetProjection(Projections.Id())
                .Add(Expression.In("Ipn", ipns));

            _criteriaForProject
                .CreateCriteria("Ipns")
                .Add(Subqueries.PropertyIn("Id", criteriaForIpns));
```

This gives me back all Projects that have any of the parts, thus the result set is Projects A, B, C, and D.

The SQL where clause generated, looks something like

```
WHERE    part1_.Id in (SELECT this_0_.Id as y0_
                   FROM   Parts this_0_
                   WHERE  this_0_.Ipn in ('2' /* @p0 */,'3' /* @p1 */))
```

My desired result would only be Projects A and B.  How can I construct the NHibernate criteria to get the result set that I need?

The number of parts I search on can vary, it can be n number of parts.

Answer (score 2):

yesterday I was working on the similar problem. 
I had to select/load all parent-objects with exactly the given list of child-objects.
I could solve this with the Criteria-API, with only one drawback (see *1 below).

```
public class Project
{
  public virtual int ProjectId{get;set;}
  public virtual IList<Part> Parts{get;set;}
  ...
}    

public class Part
{
  public virtual int PartId{get;set;}
  public virtual Project Project{get;set;} // *1 this is the drawback: I need a public property for the ForegienKey from the child to the parent 
  ...
}
```

Here comes the Criteria:

```
DetachedCriteria top = DetachedCriteria.For<Project>();
foreach(Part part in searchedParts)
{
  DetachedCriteria sub = DetachedCriteria.For<Part>();
  sub.Add(Expresion.Eq("PartId",part.PartId));
  sub.SetProjection("Project");
  top.Add(Subqueries.PropertyIn("ProjectId",sub));
}
```

Back to your example: The SQL would look like this.

```
SELECT * FROM project
WHERE 
    projectid IN ( SELECT projectid FROM part WHERE partid = 1 /* @p0 */ )
AND projectid IN ( SELECT projectid FROM part WHERE partid = 2 /* @p1 */ )
```

Basicaly I add for each child a subquery that checks for it's existance in the project and combine them with and, so only project with all that children will be selected.

Greetings

Juy Juka

## Additional Uses

I wasn't finished with my code after this and if somone needs what I had to find out, I'll add it here. I hope the additional information belongs here, but I am not sure because it's my first post on stackoverflow.com

For the following examples we need a more complex part-class:

```
public class Part
{
  public virtual int PartId{get;set;}
  public virtual Project Project{get;set;}
  public virtual PartType PartType{get;set;}
  ...
}

public class PartType
{
  public virtual int PartTypeId{get;set;}
  public virtual string Name{get;set;}
  ...
}
```

**Different criterion on child-objects**

It is possible to use the same code when you do not have the primarykey(s) of the searched parts, but would like to find the parts with other properties.

```
// I am asuming building-projects with houses, gardens, garages, driveways, etc.
IEnumerable<PartType> searchedTypes = new PartType[]{housePart, gardenPart};
// could be a parameter or users choise or what ever

DetachedCriteria top = DetachedCriteria.For<Project>();
foreach(PartType type in searchedTypes)
{ 
  DetachedCriteria sub = DetachedCriteria.For<Part>();
  sub.Add(Expresion.Eq("PartType",type)); // this is all that had to be changed. We could even use more complex operations with and, or, not, etc.
  sub.SetProjection("Project");
  top.Add(Subqueries.PropertyIn("ProjectId",sub));
}
```

Expected SQL

```
SELECT * FROM project
WHERE 
    projectid IN ( SELECT projectid FROM part WHERE parttype = 1 /* @p0 // aka. housePart */ )
AND projectid IN ( SELECT projectid FROM part WHERE parttype = 2 /* @p1 // aka. gardenPart */ )
```

**Excluding children**

To negate this and search partens who do *not* have the searched children is easily done by using Subqueries.PropertyNotIn instead of Subqueries.PropertyIn.

**Exactly/only the searched children**

This was the tricky part I had to work on the longest time. I wanted parents with exactly the given list of parts.
To stay with the building-project example: I am searching projects with a house-part and a guarden-part but no other parts

```
IEnumerable<PartType> searchedTypes = new PartType[]{housePart, gardenPart};
DetachedCriteria top = DetachedCriteria.For<Project>();
ICriterion notCriterion = null;
foreach(PartType type in searchedTypes)
{
  ICriterion subCriterion = Expresion.Eq("PartType",type);
  DetachedCriteria sub = DetachedCriteria.For<Part>();
  sub.Add(subCriterion); 
  sub.SetProjection("Project");
  top.Add(Subqueries.PropertyIn("ProjectId",sub));
  // I am collecting all valid criterions for child-objects and negate them
  subCriterion = Expresion.Not(subCriterion);
  notCriterion = notCriterion == null ? subCriterion:Expresion.And(notCriterion,subCriterion);
}
// with the negated criterions I exclude all parent-objects with an invalid child-object
DetachedCriteria not = DetachedCriteria.For<Part>();
not.Add(notCriterion);
sub.SetProjection("Project");
top.Add(Subqueries.PropertyNotIn("ProjectId",not));
```

Expected SQL

```
SELECT * FROM project
WHERE 
    projectid IN ( SELECT projectid FROM part WHERE parttype = 1 /* @p0 // aka. housePart */ )
AND projectid IN ( SELECT projectid FROM part WHERE parttype = 2 /* @p1 // aka. gardenPart */ )
AND projectid NOT IN ( SELECT projectid FROM part 
                       WHERE
                           NOT ( parttype = 1 /* @p2 // aka. housePart */ )
                       AND NOT ( parttype = 2 /* @p3 // aka. gardenPart */ )
                     )
```

(More then one house and/or one guarden is possible, since no checkon "duplicated" entries is done)

Answer (score 0):

Your query requires that we make two joins from Project to Part. This is not possible in Criteria.

**HQL**
You can express this query directly in HQL.

```
var list = session.CreateQuery( @"
    select  proj from Project proj
        inner join proj.Parts p1
        inner join proj.Parts p2
    where   p1.Id=:id1
    and p2.Id=:id2
    " )
    .SetInt32( "id1", 2 )
    .SetInt32( "id2", 3 )
    .List<Master>();
```

**Criteria**
With the Criteria API, you would query for those Projects that have one of the specified Parts, and the filter the results in C#.

Either have the criteria eager load Project.Parts, or map that as lazy="extra".

Then, using your existing criteria query from above.

```
// Load() these if necessary
List<Parts> required_parts;

var list = _criteriaForProject.List<Project>()
    .Where( proj => {
        foreach( var p in required_parts ) {
            if (!proj.Parts.Contains( p ))) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

// if _criteriaForProject is a Detached Criteria, that would be:
var list = _criteriaForProject.GetExecutableCriteria( session )
    .List<Project>()
    .Where( // etc
```

Comment: Are .List<>() and .Where() methods from LINQ? from NHibernate?  I am trying to integrate your answer into my solution, but I am not finding those methods.

Comment: ICriteria.List() is a NH method, and IEnumerable.Where() is a LINQ method.